# Can't run SDL2 project, "Cannot execute "": %1 Not a valid Win32-application"

Tags: c++, qt-creator, sdl-2

I'm trying to teach myself how to use SDL2 with Qt Creator but keep getting into these "just let me code" situations. Currently, I'm just trying to open a window with a green picture on it (doing a tutorial) but I get this error:

```
Cannot execute "": %1 not a valid Win32-application
```

I'm using MinGw 5.3.0 32bit2 as the compiler and I've managed to run other projects without this error. I tried tinkering with the Build and Run configurations, but haven't had any luck. Currently my (essential) Run configurations look like this:

```
Executable C:\...\sdl_test\debug\sdl_test.exe
Working directory: C:\...\sdl_test
```

Also for reference, here's main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

using namespace std;



int main()
{
    bool quit = false;
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Window* window = nullptr;
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("MVP", 100, 100, 600, 400,
                              SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    if(window == nullptr){
        cout << "Window could not be created." << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    SDL_Renderer* renderer = nullptr;
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1,
                                  SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    SDL_Event* mainEvent = new SDL_Event();

    SDL_Texture* grass_image = NULL;
    grass_image = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, "grass.bmp");

    SDL_Rect grass_rect;
    grass_rect.x = 10;
    grass_rect.y = 50;
    grass_rect.w = 250;
    grass_rect.h = 250;

    while(!quit && mainEvent->type != SDL_QUIT){
        SDL_PollEvent(mainEvent);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, grass_image, NULL, &grass_rect);

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    delete mainEvent;

    return 0;

}
```

Feeling hopeless, since I just want to open a window with a green rectangle on it... is that too much to ask?!

EDIT:
Here's my .pro file

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt
SOURCES += main.cpp


win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../SDL2-2.0.5/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/ -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../SDL2-2.0.5/i686-w64-mingw32/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../SDL2-2.0.5/i686-w64-mingw32/include

win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../SDL2_image-2.0.1/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/ -lmingw32 -lSDL2_image

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../SDL2_image-2.0.1/i686-w64-mingw32/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../SDL2_image-2.0.1/i686-w64-mingw32/include

win32:QMAKE_LFLAGS += -shared
```

Comment: What happens if you double-click on `C:\...\sdl_test\debug\sdl_test.exe` in Explorer? What happens if you run `C:\...\sdl_test\debug\sdl_test.exe` from `cmd`?

Comment: If I double click on the sdl_test.exe: "This operating system is not supported by this application"
Same thing if I try to run from cmd. I am running a 64-bit OS.

Comment: Just a crazy idea - are you sure the compiler you are using produces the binaries for Windows? Maybe it's a Linux cross-compiler. If you have `file` utility in your `MinGW`, can you run `file sdl_test.exe` and see what it will print?

Comment: Alright so I checked that there is a `file` utility in MSYS at `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0`. I can run the msys.bat file but once the terminal opens there is nothing to be found with `dir`. As in, I tried `file <path>/sdl_test.exe` but it can't find it. I assume I have some sort of fundamental issue that is so obvious that I can't find an answer to it. I'll write back if I manage to solve this. @Paul
EDIT: How couldn't I see this sooner? So I moved the exe file so that msys can see it and running `file sdl_test.exe` gives this: `PE32 executable for MS Windows (DLL) (console) Intel 80386 32-bit`

Answer (score 0):

The code you are showing to us works for Linux and any sane system :)

There could be a few issues for your problem:

1 - you are trying to run a 64 bit application in a 32 bit system

2 - your dll's could be corrupt

3 - your SDL dll's could be compiled with Microsoft Visual Studio (and you would need to get dll's generated with MinGW)

also, you should pass a few flags to the compiler, since you told us that you are using Qt Creator, possibly you have a projectname.pro file or a CMakeLists.txt

discover what you have, and pass those flags to the compiler:

-Wl,-subsystem,windows

and link against those libraries

-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
1. I am running a 64 bit system, shouldn't it be able to handle the 32?
2. I ran sfc /scannnow and it ended with no integrity violations found
3. I'm not sure if this is happening so I added my .pro file to the original post. I also added the -lmingw32 flag to both LIBS